How to sort data extracted with tag name
I got this line of code where I get some data from a table with tag name:
data_coverage_dict = {}
row_id = 0
# Finally: Iterate through the ul elements
for tableElement in tableElements:
  trElements = tableElement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
  # print(f'aici este tr: {tableElement.text}')
  for tdelement in trElements:
      tdelements = tdelement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'td')
      span_texts = []
      # print(f'aici este td: {tdelement.text}')

      for spanelement in tdelements:
        spanelements = spanelement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'span')
        # data_coverage_table = []
        # for index in spanelements:
        #     row_data = [cell.text for cell in spanelements[index:index]]
        #     data_coverage_table.append(row_data)
        # print(f'data table:{data_coverage_table}')

        print(f'Span element: {spanelement.text}')

In the code, I was trying to sort in a list or a dictionary, but my expected result when I got the data was this one:
Span element: Contractor Name
Span element: FANCEE PLANTS LANDSCAPING
Span element: DBA
Span element: License
Span element: 439423
Span element: City
Span element: RIVERSIDE
Span element: Status
Span element: Cancelled
Span element: Contractor Name
Span element: FANCHBILT INCORPORATED
Span element: Name Type
Span element: DBA
Span element: License
Span element: 520066
Span element: City
Span element: LAGUNA WOODS
Span element: Status
Span element: Cancelled
and the site which I want to extract data from it is in this form:

and I want to get the Contract name = with the specific contract name, I choose the find_element by tag name because the site is dynamic and I cannot use specific XPath or classes or id's.
ALso I was thinking to use a data frame but I don't know how to sort by the first and the second span element.
The code of the site is:
<table>Info</table>
 <tr>info tr</tr>
  <td>First element(in my case:Contract Name)</td
  <td>Second element(in my case:FANCEE PLANTS LANDSCAPING)</td>
Expected result:
Contractor Name = FANCEE PLANTS LANDSCAPING 


Sorry, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Your output matches the website you have shown in the screenshot. You also mention you are trying to sort something, but it is not clear what. Please, (1) improve your question to make it clearer, (2) add a representative snippet of the website you want to scrape, and (3) show us what is your expected output or result.

it seems you don't have to sort it but you have to change code which scrape it and scrape it in correct way to create pairs (name, values) (instead of adding all to one list) Eventually it may need to use (span_texts[0], span_texts[1]), (span_texts[2], span_texts[2])... (span_texts[i], span_texts[i+1]) to create pairs. it may need for i in range(0, len(span_texts), 2)

if you want to create DataFrame then you have to create columns using step 2 in slice [start:end:step] - column1 = span_texts[0:len(span_texts):2] (it start at 0) and column2 = span_texts[1:len(span_texts):2] (it starts at 1)

it seems you don't even use span_texts to keep data - and it should create you pairs at once, span_texts.append(spanelement.text), and after loop add this to global list all_rows.append(span_texts). And after all loops you can do something with data. Trying to do something inside loops can be useless. And using only print(f'Span element: {spanelement.text}') also can't resolve it.

@furas, The print function was to see what data I could get to test myself; I want to add the data in a db, so that was the reason to use a DataFrame. I will try your suggestions

You can use Selenium library in Python to find elements on a web page -
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

all_data = []

# Iterate through each table element
for tableElement in tableElements:
    data_coverage_dict = {}
    
    trElements = tableElement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
    
    for trElement in trElements:
        tdElements = trElement.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        
        if len(tdElements) == 2:
            key = tdElements[0].text.strip()
            value = tdElements[1].text.strip()
            data_coverage_dict[key] = value
    
    all_data.append(data_coverage_dict)

Check it -
for index, table_data in enumerate(all_data):
    print(f"Table {index + 1}:")
    for key, value in table_data.items():
        print(f'{key}: {value}')


I think it may have one problem - OP has many tables with the same keys (e.g. Contractor Name) and your data_coverage_dict will have values only for last table. It may need to create data_coverage_dict inside for tableElement and later add it to new list all_data

okay... it should create a separate dictionary for each table and then store all these dictionaries in a list

In my case it creates around 250 dictionaries because I got 5 td so I needed to remove the duplicates and I used:
all_unique = pd.DataFrame(all_data).drop_duplicates().to_dict('records')

It creating my 250 because when I add the key to the dictionary it takes each time you for each key and value, I got 5 keys and value so will be 5 for 50 records because I got 50 tables and that is the reason why I got 250

If there are duplicates (i.e., one key has multiple values), you need to handle it by implementing logic after finding the elements. For each table, create a new dictionary and populate it with key-value pairs from that table. If the key already exists, append the value to a list associated with that key.
